# Colored output in Runnig console in IDEA (PyCharm)

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I try log colored messages to PyCharm running console.

Yes, I have read that running console and embedded terminal is different thing, but:

For my code emited log message printed white, but it look colored if I just `print()` message. So looks like running console support colors, but I don't understand how enable it.

```
class DefaultHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        log_entry = self.format(record)
        m = re.match('^(\[.*?\])', log_entry)
        if m:
            time = click.style(m.groups()[0], fg='magenta')
            msg = click.style(log_entry[m.end():], **get_log_format(record))

            click.echo(time + msg)  # <- log emit
            print(time, msg)        # <- just print

        else:
            click.secho(log_entry, **get_log_format(record))
```

[image: Output example]

As you can see log message is white, but printed message is colored.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive what your question is, but PyCharm has support for different colors on the console.

`Console: Background, Error, output, Standard output, System output, User input`

`Log Console: Error, Expired entry, Warning`

`ANSI Colors`

You have the ability to look at the defaults and modify them through `Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Console Colors`. Is this what you're looking for?